# ffmpeg наложить дату и текст на 1080p/25k на лету

Tags: потоки-данных, ffmpeg, youtube

стоит задача сделать трансляцию с нескольких камер на youtube.
Нашел решение через ffmpeg под ubuntu

```
ffmpeg \
    -rtsp_transport tcp \
    -i 'rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.1.169:554/onvif' \
    -c:v copy \
    -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 \
    -f flv 'rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/$$$'
```

все работает норм, CPU load >5%. Но на IP-камере убогий формат даты и нет возможности название камеры нормально сделать(нет кириллицы, ограничена длина, убогий не читаемый шрифт), хочу drawtext наложить на поток дату и название камеры...

по решениям из интернет пробую так:

```
-vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
-vf "drawtext=text='название камеры'  :fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/ARIAL.TTF: box=0: boxcolor=black@0.2: borderw=3: y=25:x=25: fontcolor=white: fontsize=24,drawtext=text='%{localtime\:%d.%m.%Y  %X}'  :fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/ARIAL.TTF: box=0: boxcolor=black@0.2: borderw=3: y=25:x=w-250: fontcolor=white: fontsize=24,drawtext=text='адрес объекта'  :fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/ARIAL.TTF: box=0: boxcolor=black@0.2: borderw=3: y=h-20:x=6: fontcolor=white: fontsize=14" \
```

но CPU сразу улетает в 100%, битрейт >100 и все тормозит. Качество картинки заметно упало, я так понимаю что все из-за перекодирования видеопотока.

**подскажите, есть ли какие-то способы накладывать текст на видео лету?**

Comment: Использовать процессор помощнее. В первом случае он практически ничем не занят, во втором его просят в реальном времени декодировать и кодировать многомегабитный HD H.264 поток — есть разница. Как вариант, использовать меньшие разрешения, более слабые настройки кодера (preset ultrafast, например) и менее требовательные кодеки (MJPEG?) на выходе. Понижать качество, короче.

Answer (score 1):

Два пути:

1. перекодировать на видеокарте. Минусы - нужна карточка с поддержкой кодека и версия gstreamer (он точно умеет все делать на видеокарте, ffmpeg может натворить лишний транзит в RAM), также собранная с такой поддержкой. Качество может просесть, а может и не просесть, зависит от того, как настроите
2. Врезать дату и время как субтитры. Можно делать на CPU, качество не пострадает никак (видео не изменится), но увы - так как это субтитры, такую запись будет трудно использовать для юридических целей.